# In NetLogo Behaviour Space, how can I vary two variables in conjunction?

Tags: netlogo

I have two agent types.
I want to vary Agent1 from 90-100 and I Agent2 from 0-10.
But I want them to vary 'in step' so as Agent2 increases in number Agent 1 decreases.
How can I code that in behaviour space?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vary Agent2 from 0 to 10, and then include this in your experiment's setup commands:

```
set Agent1 100 - Agent2
```